# modification of surfaces such that the pull back of the torsion free sheaf is locally free

Tags: algebraic-geometry

We know that given a coherent torsion free sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on a non-singular algebraic surface $X$ over an algebraically closed field, there is an open subset $U\subset X$ such that $X-U$ has codimension 2 and $\mathcal{F}|_U$ is locally free.

My question is, can we find a surface $Y$ and a morphism $\varphi:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $\varphi^*(\mathcal{F})$ is locally free, and $\varphi|_{\varphi^{-1}(U)}$ is an isomorphism? The natural idea is "blow up at the points $X-U$", but I find $\varphi^*(\mathcal{F})$ is not locally free actually.

Or more roughly, can we find a "canonical surface $Y$ w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}$" such that $\varphi^*(\mathcal{F})$ is locally free? Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to look up anything precise, but I think you may want to be blowing up one of the "Fitting ideals" of $\mathcal F$.

Comment: I think it is better to ask for a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{G}$ on $Y$ such that $f_*\mathcal{G} \cong \mathcal{F}$ instead. For example, if $\mathcal{F}$ is the ideal sheaf of a point on $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, and $Y$ is the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at that point, then $f^*\mathcal{F}$ has torsion! However, it also has a natural map to $\mathcal{O}_Y$, the image of that map is locally free (the ideal sheaf of the exceptional divisor), and that locally free sheaf pushes down to recover $\mathcal{F}$.